# Python 3.9 - How to use DataClass input data variables in dictionary and in methods as input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Python 3.9 - How to use DataClass input data variables in dictionary and in methods as input

Trying to add input data variables of a dataclass in dictionary by using dict.update. However, unable to achieve this and getting: -

```
     - local variable 'jar_redownload' might be referenced before assignment. and on running the code getting below error: - 
        - NameError: name 'jar_redownload' is not defined

     - And if we go with suggestions shown in PyCharm i.e. make it global then on execution we are getting another error: - 
        - SyntaxError: annotated name 'jar_redownload' can't be global
```

Please suggest how to achieve this....Thanks!

Sample code is as below: -

```
import json
import os
import socket
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from datetime import datetime


@dataclass
class AllInputs:
    jar_redownload: bool
    abc: bool = field(init=False)
    py_file_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    py_file_path_with_file_name = __file__

    configurations_json = f'{py_file_dir_path}/' \
                          f'SearchFileConfigurationItems.json'
    with open(configurations_json) as json_file:
        configuration_items_dict = json.load(json_file)

    configuration_items_dict.update({"utc_now_date_time_in_8601_iso": datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"),
                                     "utc_now_date_time_to_append_in_file_name": datetime.utcnow().strftime(
                                             "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ"),
                                     "source_server_host_name": socket.gethostname().lower(),
                                     "source_server_fqdn_name": socket.getfqdn().lower(),
                                     "box_book_jar_redownload": jar_redownload})
```

Comment: `jar_redownload` is not really available in the namspace of your dataclass as a variable until a value is assigned to it. Try commenting out your dictionary in your dataclass and do `print(dir(AllInputs))` or `print(AllInputs.__dict__)`. You'll see that x is not available in the namespace. Since it is not available you cannot use it anywhere, including in that dictionary. The solution is to assign a default value. Or use a regular class with __init__ method to do assignment to your dictionary after x is assigned a value during instance creation.

Comment: @Firelord ...Thanks for response :) 

`print(dir(AllInputs))` not have `jar_redownload`. But, `print(AllInputs.__dict__)` has `jar_redownload`. 

And not getting why its not available as declaring it with class and supplying when creating object of class as well like `xyz = AllInputs(jar_redownload=True)`. Is it mean that `dataclass` not have this functionality and need to go with normal class as on using `__post_init__` as well, it is not available for further references like to get added in dictionary or for method of this class.

Comment: Initial line from `print(AllInputs.__dict__)` -> 
`{'__module__': '__main__', '__annotations__': {'jar_redownload': <class 'bool'>, 'abc': <class 'bool'>}`

Comment: `AllInputs.__dict__` also doesn't have jar_download. That is merely listed in annotations and in fields. When your dataclass (not its instance) is loaded in Python during runtime Python is unable to find variable jar_redownload in that class' namespace. hence NameError is thrown.